# How to debug S4 class in RStudio

Tags: r, class, debugging, rstudio, r-s4

Here is my S4 class, which is saved in separate file and currently open in RStudio:

```
setClass(
  Class = 'some_cls', 
  slots = c(some_slot = 'numeric'),
)


setGeneric("some_method", function(self)
  standardGeneric("some_method"))
setMethod("some_method", 
          signature(self = "some_cls"), 
          function(self) {
            self@some_slot <- 5
            self
          }
)
```

In another file I execute:

```
some_obj <- new('some_cls')
some_obj <- some_method(some_obj)
```

I tried to debug `some_method` as I would normally do in RStudio. I put dot next to line `self@some_slot <- 5`, in I RStudio I clicked `Source` in top right corner, but code execution did not stop at breakpoint. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a bug in RStudio; you might want to report it to them.  The underlying infrastructure in R has no problem handling a situation like yours.

For example, if the first file is called `test.R`, and you want the breakpoint on line 12, just run

```
setBreakpoint("test.R#12")
```

and execution will break when you get there.

Comment: I couldn't get `setBreakpoint` to work in my package but I was able to insert a call to `browser()` in the code which worked well

Comment: @see24:  It still works for me.  I put the original sample file in `test.R`, then sourced it, and ran `setBreakpoint("test.R#12")`.  (Line 12 is the line with the `some_slot` assignment.)  It worked fine for me, breaking on that line when I ran the two lines in the question.  In a package you probably need to build with the `--with-keep.source` option or the debug info is stripped.